# Entity Framework Fluent API Cannot Insert one-to-one

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to insert an object into a database table with Entity Framework and using code first (fluent api). Whilst doing this I keep running into one of the following errors:

> 1) InvalidOperationException: A dependent property in a
>   ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column:
>   'Id'
>
> 2) Cannot insert value into identity column with IDENTITY_INSERT set
>   to OFF

My relationship is a one-to-one however perhaps I can rework or structure the database to accomplish what I am wanting. I have also thought about utilizing a one to zero or zone even though the other object will always be required.

So I have the following database tables mapped into these C# objects (with virtual for the mapping):

```
public class test
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResultDate { get; set; }

    public virtual test_additional test_additional { get; set; }
    public virtual test_status test_status { get; set; }
}

public class test_additional
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long TestId { get; set; } //Foreign Key to test
    ...

    public virtual test test { get; set; }
}

public class test_status {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long TestId { get; set; } //Foreign Key to Test

    public long TestFormId { get; set; } //this is the object I want to insert, Foreign key to the Primary key of test_form
    ...

    public virtual test test { get; set; }
    public virtual test_form test_form { get; set; } //object mapping
}

public class test_form {
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; } //Primary Key

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public virtual test_status test_status { get; set; }
}
```

So some pretty simple objects, I've stripped members/columns that are necessary for the functionality for ease of readability.

So there are `test` objects that have an optional `test_additional` or `test_status` .

These are generated with a one to zero-or-one relationship. Which are working fine and I have the relationship defined as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<test>()
.HasOptional(e => e.test_additional)
.WithRequired(e =>e.test);

modelBuilder.Entity<test>()
.HasOptional(e => e.test_status)
.WithRequired(e => e.test);
```

Now the entity I am having trouble with is the `test_form`, if a `test_status` is defined there should always be a `test_form` associated with that. I currently have a relationship defined as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<test_form>()
.HasRequired(e => e.test_status)
.WithRequiredDependent(e => e.test_form);
```

In addition I have tried appending this config:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<test_status>()
.HasKey(e => e.TestFormId);
```

--

Here is a simple implementation of inserting this object in the database:

```
try {
    test UserTest = new test { ResultDate = DateTime.Now; }

    UOW.test.Insert(UserTest);
    UOW.Save();

    test_additional ta = new test_additional { TestId = UserTest.Id; }
    test_form tf = new test_form { FileName = "Testing.pdf"; }

    UOW.test_additional.Insert( ta );
    UOW.test_form.Insert( tf );
    UOW.Save(); //This is where it will throw that error.

    test_status status = new test_status {
        TestId = UserTest.Id;
        TestFormId = tf.Id;
    }

    UOW.test_status.Insert( status );
    UOW.Save();
} catch {
    throw;
}
```

--

I have used BreakPoints before the Unit of Work saves and I can confirm that the Id in the `test_form` object is the default of long which is 0. So I am **not** setting the **Identity Column explicitly**. Upon removing of `test_form` (in the implemented method) I can insert into the `test_additional` category and save with **no issue**.

So my question is really... are my entity relationships defined correctly? Would it be smarter to use an additional One to Zero-or-One for the `test_form` object? Why can I not insert this simple object into my database?

I have also thought about defining the virtual `test_form` object in test_status as an `ICollection`, then I could use `.HasMany(e => e.test_form).HasForeignKey(e => e.TestFormId);` so it would bind to the Foreign Key even though I would only be using 1 item for the `test_status`.

Opinions? Am I close?

Thanks again for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: do you drop the database and again migration?

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh Can you elaborate? This was not during a migration.

Comment: i had your problem. just do delete your database and migration files. after do it add new migration to create new database.

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh by golly that did it. I wonder why the database was caching an old version of my table like that?

Comment: no, in second migration a few changes don't apply to the database.

Answer (score 0):

i had your problem. just do delete your database and migration files. after do it add the new migration to create the new database.